# Combining Two functions into one

Tags: c++, qt

In my application, when the "open file" menu is clicked and a file is selected, the selected item(3D object file) is added on the `listwidget`. And if the item is double-clicked on the list, the item is displayed on the screen next to the `listwidget`. However, to simplify user interface, I want the item to be added on the list and displayed on the screen at the same time without double-click. In a nutshell, I'd like to combine the two functions, `void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_Model_triggered()` and  `MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)` into one.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_File_triggered()
{
QFileDialog diag(this);
diag.setNameFilter(tr("STL files(*.stl)"));
diag.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
diag.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
QStringList fileNames;

fileNames = diag.getOpenFileNames(this, "Open Model Files", "", "STL Files (*.stl)");
//qDebug()<<QFileInfo(fileNames).absoluteDir();
qDebug()<<fileNames;
ui->listWidget->addItems(fileNames);}
```

I tried to add the `itemDoubleClicked` function at the end of the open file function like this.

```
this->on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(ui->listWidget->currentItem());
```

However, whenever I open a file, the application stops running. I guess it's because the selected file is not added yet on the `listwidget` and in the same function the double clicked function tries to load it. Since the double click function takes `QListWidgetItem *item` as its argument. Combining those two seems not an easy task to me. Does anyone have an idea? It'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it's because the selected file is not added yet on the listwidget and in the same function the double clicked function tries to load it.

No, it's because `QListWidget::currentItem()` retrieves the item in the list widget with focus.  Merely adding items to the list widget does not give any item focus, so `QListWidget::currentItem()` returns a null pointer.

You have a couple of options to fix this.  You can call the `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked()` function with the last item in the list widget:

```
QListWidgetItem* item = ui->listWidget->item(ui->listWidget->count()-1);
this->on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(item);
```

IMHO, this is a bit messy.  Why not extract a function from `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked()` that takes a file name parameter?  Then, just call the function from both `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked()` and `on_actionOpen_File_triggered()`:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    showModel(item->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_File_triggered()
{
    QFileDialog diag(this);
    // Code for file dialog goes here.
    QStringList fileNames;

    fileNames = diag.getOpenFileNames(this, "Open Model Files", "",
                                      "STL Files (*.stl)");
    ui->listWidget->addItems(fileNames);
    showModel(fileNames.last());
}

void MainWindow::showModel(const QString& fileName)
{
    // Code to show model goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. but I keep getting the same error msg, 'ASSERT FAILURE Qvector::at "Out of Index Range: '  and I don't even know where the qvector is being used.

Comment: @user3734823 Why didn't you put this error message in your question?  Also, which of the two solutions I outlined above did you try?

Comment: @user3734823 There was a minor mistake in my first solution -- I just changed it.

Comment: I am sorry for not putting the error msg, but I couldn't find it at first. Anyway, I tried both, and the application throws the same error msg. ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::at: "index out of range"

Comment: @user3734823 Can you use a debugger (or even print statements) to determine which line of code is triggering the error message?

Comment: Problem solved! It was because ui->listwidget->currentrow was -1. By using setcurrent conditioinally, ItemDoubleClicked recognize automatically the opened model is the current one.